# Javascript/HTML - How can I randomly choose from an array and display it

Tags: javascript, html

I have started to practice html/javascript since it has been a long time since I learned the basics and I want to get better at it. Anyways, I have been working on a simple html page where I have an array of 100 movie names, and every time I load the page, I want the javascript to choose random movie from the array that I have created and display it, but whatever I did, I can't get it to display it. Please help me with where I am making a mistake. Here's what I have so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Movie Roulette</title>
        </head>

        <body>

            <h2 style="text-align:center">
                Your Movie for Tonight is: 
            </h2>

            <script>
                var theList = ["The Godfather (1972)", "The Shawshank Redemption (1994)", ... + 98 other movie names];
                var randomPick = theList[Math.floor(Math.random()*theList.length)];
                  document.body.innerHTML = randomPick;

            </script>

        </body>   
    </html>
```

Comment: It works perfectly. What issue are you facing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.body.innerHTML = randomPick;` is not right in this case.Instead create a span inside the `h2` and add an id to it. THen add the movie name inside the span

```js
var theList = ["The Godfather (1972)", "The Shawshank Redemption (1994)", 'someNameA', 'someNameB', 'someNameC', 'someNameD', 'someNameE'];
var randomPick = theList[Math.floor(Math.random() * theList.length)];
document.getElementById('movieName').innerHTML = randomPick;
```

```html
<h2 style="text-align:center">
  Your Movie for Tonight is:<span id='movieName'></span>
</h2>
```

Using `document.body.innerHTML` will remove the other dom elements from the body

```js
var theList = ["The Godfather (1972)", "The Shawshank Redemption (1994)", 'someMovA', 'someMovB', 'someMovJ', 'someMovR', 'someMovF'];
var randomPick = theList[Math.floor(Math.random() * theList.length)];
document.body.innerHTML = randomPick;
```

```html
<h2 style="text-align:center">
  Your Movie for Tonight is:
</h2>
```

Comment: Personally I wouldn't set `document.body` content like that either, but it does work.

Comment: @Pointy using `document.body` will remove other dom elements from the body, so i suugested to use separate dom elements to append the text

Comment: Agree, once again, that your answer is better of course; I'm just saying that the OP code should "work" at least basically.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to work alright @taho. Just that the array `theList` which you have declared and defined the `script` part isn't really an array of strings. Just remove the last part of it where it says`, and 98 other movies` and replace with with other strings like the first 2 movies.

And just a suggested improvement: Instead of replacing the entire `body` with the movie name, create a `div` or a `span` with an ID within the `body` and insert the movie name there.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Movie Roulette</title>
</head>

<body>

  <h2 style="text-align:center">
    Your Movie for Tonight is:
  </h2>
  
  <span id = "movie_tonight">
  </span>
  
  <script>
    var theList = ["The Godfather (1972)", "The Shawshank Redemption (1994)", "Jaws", "Kung-Fu Panda", "The Revenant", "Get Out"];
    var randomPick = theList[Math.floor(Math.random() * theList.length)];
    document.getElementById("movie_tonight").innerHTML = randomPick;
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```